SQL Server (2014) How to extract one or two possible values fromS SRS Catalog table
SQL Server 2014, ReportServer 2008 db, Catalog table, Parameter column returns the following string:
<Parameters>
  <UserProfileState>0</UserProfileState>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>dateFrom</Name>
    <Type>DateTime</Type>
    <Nullable>False</Nullable>
    <AllowBlank>False</AllowBlank>
    <MultiValue>False</MultiValue>
    <UsedInQuery>True</UsedInQuery>
    <State>MissingValidValue</State>
    <Prompt>Results from:</Prompt>
    <DynamicPrompt>False</DynamicPrompt>
    <PromptUser>True</PromptUser>
    <DynamicDefaultValue>True</DynamicDefaultValue>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>dateTo</Name>
    <Type>DateTime</Type>
    <Nullable>False</Nullable>
    <AllowBlank>False</AllowBlank>
    <MultiValue>False</MultiValue>
    <UsedInQuery>True</UsedInQuery>
    <State>MissingValidValue</State>
    <Prompt>Results to:</Prompt>
    <DynamicPrompt>False</DynamicPrompt>
    <PromptUser>True</PromptUser>
    <Dependencies>
      <Dependency>dateFrom</Dependency>
    </Dependencies>
    <DynamicDefaultValue>True</DynamicDefaultValue>
  </Parameter>
</Parameters>

Note the number of Parameter nodes above can vary from 1 or 2 or even 3 in our case.
Question:
I just need to extract everything between all the possible values between the Name elements and nothing else, either in one column or in individual columns (doesn't matter).  So in above example it would return:
DateFrom  DateTo
(Note using SQL SERVER 2014, so limited to using SUBSTRING function)
Many thanks

If you are using SQL Server 2014, why are you still using SSRS 2008? SQL Server 2014 reached end of life earlier this year (so you really need to upgrade), but SSRs 2008 reached end of life over 5 years ago; you urgently need to upgrade that version.

While asking a question, you need to provide a minimal reproducible example:
(1) DDL and sample data population, i.e. CREATE table(s) plus INSERT T-SQL statements.
(2) What you need to do, i.e. logic and your code attempt implementation of it in T-SQL.
(3) Desired output, based on the sample data in the #1 above.
(4) Your SQL Server version (SELECT @@version;).

SQL Server 2014 supports XML queries and that certainly looks like XML formatted data. Have you tried casting it to XML (if it's not already) and querying the /Parameters/Parameter/Name/text() values?

@ThomA  ...Tell me about it!  I've been trying for years to get our organisation to upgrade the SQL Server and from Report Server to MS BI as well as using classic asp to .net MVC but falls on deaf ears so i just plod along now and have given up suggesting using any new stuff even though using old stuff does make my life more difficult!

@Yitzhak Khabinsky  I did provide 1 , 2, 3 & 4 in my orig post

There is not T-SQL for #1 in the question. That why I took the liberty and created T-SQL variable as a source for the XML in my answer below.

PLease try the following solution leveraging SQL Server's XQuery.
XQuery support is available starting from SQL Server 2005 onwards.
SQL
DECLARE @xml_param XML = 
N'<Parameters>
  <UserProfileState>0</UserProfileState>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>dateFrom</Name>
    <Type>DateTime</Type>
    <Nullable>False</Nullable>
    <AllowBlank>False</AllowBlank>
    <MultiValue>False</MultiValue>
    <UsedInQuery>True</UsedInQuery>
    <State>MissingValidValue</State>
    <Prompt>Results from:</Prompt>
    <DynamicPrompt>False</DynamicPrompt>
    <PromptUser>True</PromptUser>
    <DynamicDefaultValue>True</DynamicDefaultValue>
  </Parameter>
  <Parameter>
    <Name>dateTo</Name>
    <Type>DateTime</Type>
    <Nullable>False</Nullable>
    <AllowBlank>False</AllowBlank>
    <MultiValue>False</MultiValue>
    <UsedInQuery>True</UsedInQuery>
    <State>MissingValidValue</State>
    <Prompt>Results to:</Prompt>
    <DynamicPrompt>False</DynamicPrompt>
    <PromptUser>True</PromptUser>
    <Dependencies>
      <Dependency>dateFrom</Dependency>
    </Dependencies>
    <DynamicDefaultValue>True</DynamicDefaultValue>
  </Parameter>
</Parameters>';

SELECT c.value('(Name/text())[1]', 'VARCHAR(100)') AS param_name
FROM @xml_param.nodes('/Parameters/Parameter') AS t(c);

SELECT @xml_param.query('data(/Parameters/Parameter/Name)').value('.', 'VARCHAR(256)');

